# We need to get rid of / disambiguate the [float] tag!

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Currently, the [float](/questions/tagged/float) tag is used as a CSS tag representing the `float` property for floating elements to the left or right. There are currently **2,257** questions tagged with it.

However, **only 853** of these questions are tagged with [css](/questions/tagged/css), leaving **1,404** questions tagged otherwise.

My question: **how does this constitute the tag to be for CSS use?** It's clearly used a lot more often for non-CSS purposes. This tag is ambiguous and needs to be destroyed.

An easy way to fix the CSS problem is to
retag all questions matching `[css][float]` to `[css][css-float]`.
I don't know if this can be easily done by a moderator or developer, but that takes care of a huge chunk.

The rest of these questions I'm assuming all belong to the [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point). At least, I haven't found any questions where the use seems to contradict this statement.

So, steps to fix this problem:

1. Retag [css](/questions/tagged/css)[float](/questions/tagged/float) → [css](/questions/tagged/css)[css-float](/questions/tagged/css-float)
2. Retag all remaining [float](/questions/tagged/float) → [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point)
3. Do something with the [float](/questions/tagged/float) so it doesn't cause problems. Some options:
   a. Blacklist [float](/questions/tagged/float) and its synonym [floats](/questions/tagged/floats)
   b. Synonymize [float](/questions/tagged/float) and [floats](/questions/tagged/floats) into [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point)
   c. Synonymize [float](/questions/tagged/float) and [floats](/questions/tagged/floats) into [css-float](/questions/tagged/css-float)

Comment: I think, perhaps, [tag:css-float] make make more sense than [tag:css-floating] since "float" is more in line (heh) with the css attribute.

Comment: There may also be a few discussing LaTeX floats ([look like 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex+float)). But any way you look at it this tag should probably be disambiguated.

Comment: [css-floating]?  What the hell.  Whose idea was that?  It's [css-float].

Comment: @Robert: I have no idea, but it existed so I used it. :P Go track down who the first person to tag a question with that was?

Comment: @animuson: I fixed it.  That was a no-brainer.

Comment: It gets worse.  [floating] has 128 questions.

Comment: The only thing that bothers me about [css-floating]/[css-float] is *its existence*. But since that's justified, here's one that's unjustified: the use of [html][css] or [html][css][css3] + [css-selectors][css-floating] to fill the Tags field with up to 5 tags for the sake of filling it.

Answer (score 2):

[float](/questions/tagged/float) is now gone. Rest in peace [float](/questions/tagged/float), though you will not be missed.

Comment: May [float] float off to heaven (or some bad place where all burninated tags belong)...